# Can't get Python to recognize a string

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm in the process of learning Python,
I've been trying out [the "Count Green Eggs and Ham" project](https://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/1i6sax/challenge_count_and_fix_green_eggs_and_ham/).

The issue I'm running into is  I can't get the program to recognize **Sam-i-am** and replace it with **Sam-I-am**.

What I have so far is(ignore comments):

```
f = open('green_eggs_and_ham_text_with_errors.txt')
g = open('greeneggsandhamfixed.txt', 'w')


def CapitalEye(a):
        lstitm = list(a)
        a=''
        for ind, ltr in enumerate(lstitm):
            if ltr == 'i':
                lstitm[ind] = 'I'
            for i in lstitm:
                a += i
for line in f:
    splt = line.split(' ')

    for i, itm in enumerate(splt):
        if itm == 'i':
            splt[i]='I'
        elif itm == 'Sam-i-am':
            CapitalEye(itm)
            splt[i]=itm
        elif itm == 'Sam-i-am!':
            CapitalEye(itm)
            splt[i]=itm
        elif itm == 'Sam-i-am.':
            CapitalEye(itm)
            splt[i]=itm
        elif itm == 'Sam-i-am?':
            CapitalEye(itm)
            splt[i]=itm
        elif itm == 'Sam-i-am,':
            CapitalEye(itm)
            splt[i]=itm
    #print(splt)
    print(' '.join(splt))
    #splt = ' '.join(splt)        
    #g.write(splt)
#g.close()
#f.close()
```

Comment: Direct link for everyone else https://pastebin.com/XMY48CnN

Answer (score 1):

Try using the replace method

```
 string = 'Same-i-am'
 string = string.replace('i','I')
```

Comment: That will capitalize any "i" though, so "running" becomes "runnIng"

Comment: You can do string.replace("-i-","-I-") if that suits the OPs needs

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are making this harder than necessary. 
I suggest try searching for all instances of 

`i` (space after the i)

and 

`-i-`

```
def CapitalEye(a):
    a = a.replace('i ', 'I ')
    a = a.replace('-i-', '-I-')
    return a
```

The input `a` would be the text file, in this case I simply used raw text

```
CapitalEye("""
    i am Sam
    Sam i am

    That Sam-i-am!
    That Sam-i-am!
    i do not like that Sam-i-am!
    ...
""")
```

---

### How to do this writing to a file

#### Mode

You will need to include a mode argument in order to specify if you're reading or writing to a file. here are some of the available modes
The modes are:

- ‘r’ – Read mode which is used when the file is only being read
- ‘w’ – Write mode which is used to edit and write new information to the file (any existing files with the same name will be erased when this mode is activated)
- ‘a’ – Appending mode, which is used to add new data to the end of the file; that is new information is automatically amended to the end
- ‘r+’ – Special read and write mode, which is used to handle both actions when working with a file

```
    def CapitalEye(a):
        a = a.replace('i ', 'I ')
        a = a.replace('-i-', '-I-')
        return a


    # write file to variable
    file1 = open("testfile.txt", "r")
    file2 = open("testfile2.txt", "w")
    file2.write(CapitalEye(file1.read()))
```

Comment: for this particular project I need to go through the .txt file and write the correction to another. How would I get this to work for that functionality?

Comment: Updated the answer to display how you could do that

Comment: If this solution worked for you, please check mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is great for this type of stuff

```
import re

a = "sam-i-am"
b = "so i was going to go to see her but i didn't"

re.sub("-i-","-I-", a)

sam-I-am

#use [^a-z] to match only non a-z characters on both sides (i.e. spaces/punctuation)

re.sub("[^a-z]i[^a-z]"," I ", b)

so I was going to go to see her but I didn't
```